# import a class from a file py in a subdirectory

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.6, subdirectory

i have a python3 project with a subdirectory GTFSr with a file gtfsr that have a class GTFSR

```
---main.py  <--there is a class UTILITY
|----GTFSr
      |----gtfsrdb.py <--here i have GTFSrDB class that extend UTILITY.
```

when in main i type:

```
from GTFSr.gtfsrdb import GTFSrDB
```

I have this error:

```
`ImportError: cannot import name 'GTFSrDB' from 'GTFSr.gtfsrdb' (.....\GTFSr\gtfsrdb.py)`
```

UPDATE  traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "xxx\GTFSr\gtfsrdb.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ReadProtocolBufferFiles import Utils
  File "xxx\ReadProtocolBufferFiles.py", line 9, in <module>
    from GTFSr.gtfsrdb import GTFSrDB
ImportError: cannot import name 'GTFSrDB' from 'GTFSr.gtfsrdb' (C:\xxxxxx\GTFSr\gtfsrdb.py)
```

Some Tips?
thanks
Regards

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question says you have a class ``GTFSR``, but your code tries to import a thing named ``GTFSrDB``. Is this mismatch intentional?

Comment: i have folder: GTFSr,   file: gtfsrdb.py,    class: GTFSrDB..  I want import this class from main

Comment: Please post the entire traceback, formatted as code.

Comment: You have a circular import ``GTFSr.gtfsrdb`` -> ``ReadProtocolBufferFiles.Utils`` -> ``GTFSr.gtfsrdb.GTFSrDB``.

Comment: yes i must put UTILITY class in another file?

Answer (score -2):

I think you need an `__init__.py` inside "GTFSr". Create an empty `GTFSr/__init__.py` and try your code please. Thanks.

Comment: also con __init.py i have this error: "cannot import name 'GTFSrDB' from 'GTFSr.gtfsrdb' "

Comment: ``__init__.py`` is not strictly needed. The folder will be a namespace package without it. Whether the import works or not is not changed by this.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't it be from GTFSr.gtfsr and not GTFSr.gtfsrdb ?